# Dynamic Where clause in sql with IN statement in it

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

How do I write a query in SQL where when the string variable is not '' we include the WHERE clause and check where the ID exists in the list or not?
The following does not seem to work.

```
DECLARE @var varchar(20)
DECLARE @clause varchar(20)
DECLARE @sql varchar(20)

SET @var= '1,2,3'
IF @var <> ''
SET @clause=' WHERE ID IN ('+ @var + ')'

SET @sql='SELECT  [ID]
  ,[SOURCE]
  ,[LAST_KEY]
FROM [oms].[dbo].[MIGRATION]' 

EXEC (@sql + @clause)
```

Error Message:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: You will need to elaborate on "doesn't work" before you will get a useful answer.  Generally the approach is to print the SQL to make sure it's created correctly, run it and debug it in the usual fashion.  Personally I'd put the @var parameters into a temp table and join rather than use dynamic SQL but first things first.

Comment: Try to increase the size of your varchar variables. 20 seems to be not enough to hold the whole dynamic SQL syntax

Comment: Have you tried combining everything into a single variable? E.g instead of `EXEC (@sql + @clause)` do a `SET @sql = @sql + @clause` and then `EXEC (@sql)`. And yes do increase their size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase your @sql variable's length to MAX like

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)
```

You have defined 20 length which is not enough to store whole query in that variable. Also remove @clause variable and change your code like below. You can also print whole query by `print @sql` and check what is wrong in that.

```
DECLARE @var varchar(500)
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)

SET @var= '1,2,3'

SET @sql = 'SELECT  [ID], 
                    [SOURCE], 
                    [LAST_KEY] 
            FROM    [oms].[dbo].[MIGRATION]' 

IF @var IS NOT NULL AND @var <> ''
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE ID IN ('+ @var + ')'
END

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of length for variable **@sql**. Please change it from @sql varchar(20) to @sql varchar(max) will resolve your issue.

Below is the code for the same

```
  DECLARE @var varchar(20)
DECLARE @clause varchar(20)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SET @var= '1,2,3'
IF @var <> ''
SET @clause=' WHERE ID IN ('+ @var + ')'

SET @sql='SELECT  [ID]
  ,[SOURCE]
  ,[LAST_KEY]
FROM [oms].[dbo].[MIGRATION]' 

EXEC (@sql + @clause)
```